# Post-hoc output and GLMM output don't add up

Tags: r, mixed-model, glmm, post-hoc

I've been running GLMMs in the R package "glmmadmb" looking at the effects of different sizes of pan trap on the abundance of their catch, using the following code: `glmm5 <- glmmadmb(ab$Totalpolls ~ ab$Pan_size+ab$Treatment+log(ab$Nectar+1)+log(ab$Mean.nectar+1)+ab$Max_temp+ab$Season+(1|Year)+(1|Transect), data = ab, zeroInflation = FALSE, family = "nbinom")`

The basic output look like this:

```
Anova(glmm5)

Analysis of Deviance Table (Type II tests)
Response: ab$Total_polls  Df Chisq Pr(>Chisq)    
ab$Pan_size               3 41.6487  4.763e-09 ***
ab$Treatment              2 14.8347  0.0006007 ***
log(ab$Nectar + 1)        1  8.0988  0.0044295 ** 
log(ab$Mean.nectar + 1)   1  5.0591  0.0244971 *  
ab$Max_temp               1  8.5233  0.0035062 ** 
ab$Season                 4 46.4576  1.978e-09 ***
Residuals               212                       
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

and...

> summary(glmm5)

```
Call:
glmmadmb(formula = ab$Total_polls ~ ab$Pan_size + ab$Treatment + 
log(ab$Nectar + 1) + log(ab$Mean.nectar + 1) + ab$Max_temp + 
ab$Season + (1 | ab$Year) + (1 | ab$Transect), data = ab, 
family = "nbinom", zeroInflation = FALSE)

AIC: 855.6 

Coefficients:
                        Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)              -1.1797     0.5312   -2.22  0.02638 *  
ab$Pan_size2              0.5272     0.1587    3.32  0.00089 ***
ab$Pan_size5.5            0.0926     0.1668    0.56  0.57882    
ab$Pan_size12             0.9026     0.1538    5.87  4.4e-09 ***
ab$Treatment24            0.0540     0.1368    0.39  0.69286    
ab$Treatment48            0.4973     0.1291    3.85  0.00012 ***
log(ab$Nectar + 1)        0.0739     0.0260    2.85  0.00443 ** 
log(ab$Mean.nectar + 1)   0.0934     0.0415    2.25  0.02450 *  
ab$Max_temp              -0.0513     0.0176   -2.92  0.00351 ** 
ab$Season5                0.6176     0.2051    3.01  0.00260 ** 
ab$Season6                1.2434     0.2229    5.58  2.4e-08 ***
ab$Season7                0.7909     0.2338    3.38  0.00072 ***
ab$Season8                0.6476     0.3554    1.82  0.06840 .  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Number of observations: total=228, ab$Year=2, ab$Transect=19 
Random effect variance(s):
Group=ab$Year
             Variance   StdDev
(Intercept) 1.142e-07 0.000338
Group=ab$Transect
            Variance StdDev
(Intercept)  0.01727 0.1314

Negative binomial dispersion parameter: 5.6367 (std. err.: 2.0044)

Log-likelihood: -411.816
```

Which shows that pan sizes 12 and 2 are significantly different to size 1, and size 5.5 isn't significantly different at all. However, when I put this model through post hoc tests using the following code: `summary(glht(glmm5, lsm(pairwise ~ ab$Pan_size)))` (using the glht interface in R package "Lsmeans") it gives me this:

```
     Simultaneous Tests for General Linear Hypotheses

Fit: glmmadmb(formula = ab$Total_polls ~ ab$Treatment + ab$Pan_size + 
log(ab$Nectar + 1) + log(ab$Mean.nectar + 1) + ab$Max_temp + 
ab$Season + (1 | ab$Year) + (1 | ab$Transect), data = ab, 
family = "nbinom", zeroInflation = FALSE)

Linear Hypotheses:
              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
1 - 2 == 0     -0.1465     0.1239  -1.182  0.62507    
1 - 5.5 == 0   -0.3086     0.1252  -2.464  0.06256 .  
1 - 12 == 0    -0.6975     0.1421  -4.907  < 0.001 ***
2 - 5.5 == 0   -0.1621     0.1063  -1.525  0.40911    
2 - 12 == 0    -0.5510     0.1666  -3.308  0.00498 ** 
5.5 - 12 == 0  -0.3889     0.1327  -2.931  0.01685 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
(Adjusted p values reported -- single-step method)
```

Which suggests that size 12 is not better than size 1 and that size two is also not better than size 1; it also indicates that size 5.5 is better than size 1. This all seems to contradict what's in the model summary, which has got me slightly puzzled. All of the other post hoc tests I've run for the other categorical variables in the model have run fine and present results as expected. I've tried changing the position of `ab$pan_size` in the model, but that doesn't improve things.

Here's a list of the basic code that I'm using:

```
#pollinator abundance vs. pan trap size and time left active

ab<-read.csv("Total_polls.csv")

ab
names(ab)
str(ab)
summary(ab)

# create factors from numerical variables

ab$Year<-as.factor(ab$Year)
ab$Transect<-as.factor(ab$Transect)
ab$Treatment<-as.factor(ab$Treatment)
ab$Pan_size<-as.factor(ab$Pan_size)
ab$Season<-as.factor(ab$Season)

library(glmmADMB)
library(RVAideMemoire)
library(car)

glmm5 <- glmmadmb(ab$Total_polls ~ ab$Treatment+ab$Pan_size+log(ab$Nectar+1)+log(ab$Mean_nectar+1)+ab$Max_temp+ab$Season+(1|ab$Year)+(1|ab$Transect), data = ab, zeroInflation = FALSE, family = "nbinom")

Anova(glmm5) #(Package: car)
summary(glmm5) 

# pairwise multiple comparisons tests between multi-level fixed effects (pan_size, treatment (time), and season)

library(multcomp)
library(lsmeans)

glht1 <- (glht(glmm5, lsm(pairwise ~ ab$Pan_size)))
glht2 <- (glht(glmm5, lsm(pairwise ~ ab$Treatment)))
glht3 <- (glht(glmm5, lsm(pairwise ~ ab$Season)))

summary(glht1)
```

I'm using R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10) -- "Wooden Christmas-Tree". Could anyone help me to sort this out? I'm not exactly stats savvy, so you may have to be kind with the mathematical language.

Many thanks,
Tom

Comment: try out a simple model that includes *only* `Pan_size` and see whether the summary and lsm results agree with each other. I'm not quite sure what `glht` is doing about setting  reference levels of all the other variables?  Any chance of a *reproducible* example?  Also, you should probably use the `data=` argument rather than using `ab$` throughout your `glmmadmb` call ...

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply @BenBolker, I'll try that out. What would you need for a workable example (sorry - I'm a bit new here).

Comment: @BenBolker using the simpler model the post-hoc output appears to mirror that of the summary much more closely now, thanks for the advice!

Comment: If you think you've answered your own question satisfactorily, you can post an answer.  If you want more advice about a MWE, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example ...

Comment: @BenBolker it would potentially be good to know why exactly this is happening in case it's a problem with my data/code. I've included the basic code in an edit above and here is a link to the ".csv" dataset for the analysis I was having an issue with: https://www.dropbox.com/s/q07st1mpnxmgq3l/Total_polls.csv?dl=0